# How to import files from computer?

Tags: aide-ide

I have been making a simple program on my computer using Dr. Java, and I would like to know how to move it to my android on AIDE. I can easily get the files onto the android, I just can't figure out how to make AIDE compile and run them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using My Files or the file browser you prefer,  move your entire project directory into a folder call AppProjects. Should be fairly easy to open from there. Also you will want to make sure the directory is set up correctly. If all else fails, you can always recreate the project using AIDE and copy your java files into the java folder and XML files into the layout folder, and your images and icons into the drawable folders. These folders are automatically generated by AIDE so you don't have to create them.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the source files normally as you do with other files but Desktop's Java is not always same as Android's.  So it needs some more coding and editing to make the code work as you want. But if the code is so simple, it can work.